# Has Google modified its preferred MX records?

Tags: gmail, mx

I have a client whose DNS records have been pointing to Googles MX servers for years, and these MX records are coded into my setup scripts for new DNS setups - however toolbox.googleapps.com was this morning advising the DNS records were incorrect. (I've never looked at this before, so I don't know how long this has been the case)

I'm wondering if this is domain specific, or Google specific and/or if there are problems with my template and/or if I should be updating it.

My old records were:

```
1   aspxmx.l.google.com
5   alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
5   alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
10  aspmx2.googlemail.com
10  aspmx3.googlemail.com
10  aspmx4.googlemail.com
10  aspmx5.googlemail.com
```

The new records are:

```
1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

I specifically note the first MX record - note that mine is asp**x**mx.google.com while the new one does not have the x.

Do google have different MX records for different services, or have the records I've been using been deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they harmonised them some 10 years ago if I recall well. The "new" values were already there in 2014:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140921234242/https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125

In my experience, it's always worth keeping an eye on changes at Google, for instance by subscribing to their admin newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a search for `gmail MX records` the first result is https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en

They make it clear that the current records are

```
 host       TTL        Priority       Value
Blank or @  3600    MX    1     ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @  3600    MX    5     ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @  3600    MX    5     ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @  3600    MX   10     ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Blank or @  3600    MX   10     ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```

Comment: Thank you - I am aware of that link, however it does not really answer my question - to whit - Do google have different MX records for different [mail] services or have the records I use been deprecated?  Should I be changing my existing clients MX records?

Comment: You would have to ask Google that, suffice to say that if that is what they say the MX records are, I would be changing old ones to that.